# docker-compose does not initalize container environment variables

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am trying to execute simple code.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  test-environment:
    image: alpine:3.9
    environment: 
      VAR1: 'variable 1'
      VAR2: '222'
    command: echo variable1 = $VAR1; variable2 = $VAR2
```

Expected behavior: to see in output

```
variable1 = variable 1; variable2 = 222
```

But after

```
docker-compose up
```

i got next:

```
WARNING: The VAR1 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The VAR2 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
Recreating project_test-environment_1 ... done
Attaching to project_test-environment_1
test-environment_1  | variable1 = ; variable2 =
project_test-environment_1 exited with code 0
```

It seems like environment variables were not initialized. Using alternative syntax

```
environment:
 - VAR1='variable 1'
 - VAR2=222
```

given the same result too.

docker info output:

```
Containers: 3
Running: 0
Paused: 0
Stopped: 3
Images: 5
Server Version: 18.09.2
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Supports d_type: true
Native Overlay Diff: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
 Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file local logentries 
 splunk syslog
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 9754871865f7fe2f4e74d43e2fc7ccd237edcbce
runc version: 09c8266bf2fcf9519a651b04ae54c967b9ab86ec
init version: fec3683
Security Options:
 seccomp
 Profile: default
Kernel Version: 4.9.125-linuxkit
Operating System: Docker for Windows
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 973.8MiB
Name: linuxkit-00155d694b07
ID: NA32:YPM3:D5GL:JQBM:H4BN:LE2B:4HLN:5B4A:AI7T:6SDS:LSVZ:P74L
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): true
 File Descriptors: 22
 Goroutines: 47
 System Time: 2019-05-14T08:44:02.5767035Z
 EventsListeners: 1
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
Product License: Community Engine
```

Does anyone has any ideas to solve problem?

P.S. Sorry for my English.

Comment: This line **command: echo variable1 = $VAR1; variable2 = $VAR2** tells you  will specify the those value form outside. Try this **VAR1="HELLO" VAR2="THERE" docker-compose up -d**

Comment: **command: '/bin/sh -c "echo $$VAR1 $VAR2"'**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
version: '3'
services:
  test-environment:
    image: alpine:3.9
    environment:
      VAR1: 'variable 1'
      VAR2: '222'
    command: '/bin/sh -c "echo $$VAR1 $$VAR2"'
```

**Important points:**

1. [variable-substitution](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution)
2. docker inspect  command to check if env variables are configured properly for that container.
3. I used version 3 as my docker-compose do not support the version you are using.
4. The .env file feature only works when you use the docker-compose up command and does not work with docker stack deploy.
5. You can use a $$ (double-dollar sign) when your configuration needs a literal dollar sign. This also prevents Compose from interpolating a value, so a $$ allows you to refer to environment variables that you don’t want processed by Compose.
6. If you forget and use a single dollar sign ($), Compose interprets the value as an environment variable and warns you:

> WARNING: The VAR1 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
>   WARNING: The VAR2 variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.

Comment: Yeah. that's what 2 solutions for 1 problem :)

Answer (score 1):

the `environment` option specifies which vars will be passed **to the container**. they are not available outside in the docker-compose file.
if you need env vars for your docker-compose file, create on the same directory a `.env` file:

```
#.env
VAR1=variable1
VAR2=222
```

and now it should work for `docker-compose up`

**note**

remove the `environment` option from the docker-compose - unless you need the vars inside the container, it makes no sense.

Comment: Just checked your approach. It worked.    Same problem 2 solutions Great. Upvoting the answer